# How to get html data (table) from page and put it inside a div?

Tags: php, jquery

I have a page, a feed and I want to refresh it without the page loading, i've got a script to do that:

```
<script text="text/javascript">
function ajaxQuery(){
    // some stuff inside here to perform call
    $.ajax({
        url: 'purefeed.php',
        success: function(data) {
            // Here I want to put the data to show inside my div with id: "contents".

}

   });


}
</script>
```

My purefeed.php displays a table without any styles.

Inside my div I'm calling the function with an interval:
setInterval(ajaxQuery(), 2000);

How can I do it?

Comment: `$('div').html(data)`

Comment: Not working, shows nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add data as `html` to some page element use `html()` method:

```
success: function(data) {
    $('#contents').html(data);
}
```

Also, **correct** code for `setInterval` is:

```
setInterval(ajaxQuery, 2000);  // note - NO ()
```

Comment: Open developers console and debug - is request to server sent? What data is returned?

Comment: It sais 'ajaxQuery is not defined'

Comment: Make sure function's definition is __before__ it's execution.

Comment: Now it doesn't show an error in the developers console, but still doesn't show anything.

Comment: Yup, I made a typo 